# Carousel dependent on bootstrap.js is not working inside a vue.js component

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, bootstrap-4, carousel

In my `public/index.html` file I have included

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

In my vue component I have:

```
<div id="carousel" class="carousel slide">
 <div class="carousel-inner">
  <div class="dialog carousel-item active">
   <div class="d-block w-100">
    <span>You have <router-link to="/invitations">{{invitationsPending}} Pending Invitation(s)</router-link></span>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dialog carousel-item">
   <div class="d-block w-100">
    <span>Redeem your Free Coffee!</span>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Code taken from https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/.

The carousel doesn't seem to move. Even if I manually try to slide/move the text. I put the same carousel in my `public/index.html` and the carousel works. I suppose somehow the browser is not able to get the script tag.

I also tried putting this in my mounted hook:

```
mounted(){
 let script = document.createElement('script')
 script.setAttribute('src', 'https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js')
 document.body.appendChild(script)
}
```

but nothing seems to work... How to get the carousel working?

Comment: you must have more that one slide!

Comment: There are two in this case. My actual code has about 4-5 depending on certain conditions.